# How to handle error `The getter was called on null` by using dependency injection from fire store using flutter bloc

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-bloc

I am facing an error as the below one while retrieving data from `FireStore`:

```
The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building BlocBuilder<AppCubit, AppStates>(dirty, state: _BlocBuilderBaseState<AppCubit, AppStates>#783ea):
The getter 'cover' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: cover
```

So realised that this error because of the `dependency injection` and I found that `userModel` is `null` and this is the `userModel` class I have:

```
class UserModel {
  String name;
  String email;
  String phone;
  String uId;
  String image;
  String cover;
  String bio;
  bool isEmailVerified;

  UserModel({
    this.name,
    this.email,
    this.phone,
    this.uId,
    this.image,
    this.cover,
    this.bio,
    this.isEmailVerified,
  });

  UserModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    email = json['email'];
    name = json['name'];
    phone = json['phone'];
    uId = json['uId'];
    image = json['image'];
    cover = json['cover'];
    bio = json['bio'];
    isEmailVerified = json['isEmailVerified'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    return {
      'name': name,
      'email': email,
      'phone': phone,
      'uId': uId,
      'image': image,
      'cover': cover,
      'bio': bio,
      'isEmailVerified': isEmailVerified,
    };
  }
}
```

and I created a `getUserData` method in my `Cubit` class as the below method:

```
  UserModel userModel;

  void getUserData() {
    emit(AppGetUserLoadingState());
    FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').doc(uId).get().then((value) {
      // print(value.data());
      userModel = UserModel.fromJson(value.data());
      emit(
        AppGetUserSuccessState(),
      );
    }).catchError((error) {
      print(error.toString());
      emit(
        AppGetUserErrorState(
          error.toString(),
        ),
      );
    });
  }
```

as I am calling this method when the app starts in the main like the below code:

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocProvider(
      create: (BuildContext context) => AppCubit()..getUserData()..handleScroll(),
      child: BlocConsumer<AppCubit, AppStates>(
        listener: (context, state) {},
        builder: (context, state) {...},
      ),
    );
  }
```

and this is below one of multiple parts which I have the error:

```
DecorationImage(
                                  image: NetworkImage(
                                    '${userModel.cover}',
                                  ),
                                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                ),
```

and this is the full class I am using :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';
import 'package:mysocially/shared/cubit/cubit.dart';
import 'package:mysocially/shared/cubit/states.dart';
import 'package:mysocially/styles/icon_broken.dart';

class SettingsScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const SettingsScreen({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocConsumer<AppCubit, AppStates>(
      listener: (context, state) {},
      builder: (context, state) {
        var userModel = AppCubit.get(context).userModel;
        // print(userModel.cover);

        return Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Container(
                height: 190.0,
                child: Stack(
                  alignment: AlignmentDirectional.bottomCenter,
                  children: [
                    Align(
                      alignment: AlignmentDirectional.topCenter,
                      child: Container(
                        width: double.infinity,
                        height: 140.0,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                            topLeft: Radius.circular(4.0),
                            topRight: Radius.circular(4.0),
                          ),
                          image: DecorationImage(
                                  image: NetworkImage(
                                    '${userModel.cover}',
                                  ),
                                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    CircleAvatar(
                      radius: 51.0,
                      backgroundColor:
                          Theme.of(context).scaffoldBackgroundColor,
                      child: CircleAvatar(
                        // radius: responsive.height * 0.025,
                        radius: 50.0,
                        backgroundImage: NetworkImage(
                          '${userModel.image}',
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 5.0,
              ),
              Text(
                '${userModel.name}',
                style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyText1,
              ),
              Text(
                '${userModel.bio}',
                style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.caption,
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20.0),
                child: Row(
                  children: [
                    Expanded(
                      child: InkWell(
                        child: Column(
                          children: [
                            Text(
                              '100',
                              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.subtitle2,
                            ),
                            Text(
                              'Posts',
                              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.caption,
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                        onTap: () {},
                      ),
                    ),
                    Expanded(
                      child: InkWell(
                        child: Column(
                          children: [
                            Text(
                              '100',
                              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.subtitle2,
                            ),
                            Text(
                              'Posts',
                              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.caption,
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                        onTap: () {},
                      ),
                    ),
                    Expanded(
                      child: InkWell(
                        child: Column(
                          children: [
                            Text(
                              '62',
                              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.subtitle2,
                            ),
                            Text(
                              'Photos',
                              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.caption,
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                        onTap: () {},
                      ),
                    ),
                    Expanded(
                      child: InkWell(
                        child: Column(
                          children: [
                            Text(
                              '200',
                              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.subtitle2,
                            ),
                            Text(
                              'Followers',
                              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.caption,
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                        onTap: () {},
                      ),
                    ),
                    Expanded(
                      child: InkWell(
                        child: Column(
                          children: [
                            Text(
                              '600',
                              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.subtitle2,
                            ),
                            Text(
                              'Followings',
                              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.caption,
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                        onTap: () {},
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              Row(
                children: [
                  Expanded(
                    child: OutlinedButton(
                      onPressed: () {},
                      child: Text('Add Photos'),
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    width: 10.0,
                  ),
                  OutlinedButton(
                    onPressed: () {},
                    child: Icon(
                      IconBroken.Edit,
                      size: 20.0,
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

I tried to handle this by using `GetX` state management by uing `init: Get.find(),`, but I failed to handle this error using `flutter_bloc`..

for more infos: The data doesn't retrieved in the first login, but it retrieved when I restart the app but it gives me this error for a second and gives me back the data..

Any Suggestions here?

I hope I mentioned all the infos needed..

#Edited
So I figured something so here's I put a condition at the begining of builder as the below code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';
import 'package:mysocially/modules/new_post/new_post_screen.dart';
import 'package:mysocially/shared/components/components.dart';
import 'package:mysocially/shared/cubit/cubit.dart';
import 'package:mysocially/shared/cubit/states.dart';
import 'package:mysocially/styles/icon_broken.dart';

class SocialLayout extends StatelessWidget {
  const SocialLayout({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocConsumer<AppCubit, AppStates>(
      listener: (context, state) {},
      builder: (context, state) {
        var cubit = AppCubit.get(context);
        if (state is AppGetUserSuccessState) {
          return Scaffold(
            extendBody: true,
            appBar: AppBar(
              title: Text(
                cubit.titles[cubit.currentIndex],
              ),
              actions: [
                IconButton(
                  onPressed: () {},
                  icon: Icon(IconBroken.Notification),
                ),
                IconButton(
                  onPressed: () {},
                  icon: Icon(IconBroken.Search),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            body: cubit.screens[cubit.currentIndex],
            bottomNavigationBar: AnimatedOpacity(
              opacity: cubit.show ? 1.0 : 0.0,
              duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500),
              child: BottomNavigationBar(
                currentIndex: cubit.currentIndex,
                onTap: (index) {
                  cubit.changeBottomNavIndex(index);
                },
                items: [
                  BottomNavigationBarItem(
                      icon: Icon(IconBroken.Home), label: 'Home'),
                  BottomNavigationBarItem(
                      icon: Icon(IconBroken.Chat), label: 'Chat'),
                  // BottomNavigationBarItem(
                  //     icon: Icon(IconBroken.Paper_Upload,), label: 'Post'),
                  BottomNavigationBarItem(
                      icon: Icon(IconBroken.Location), label: 'Location'),
                  BottomNavigationBarItem(
                      icon: Icon(IconBroken.Setting), label: 'Settings'),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            floatingActionButtonLocation:
                FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerDocked,
            floatingActionButton: AnimatedOpacity(
              opacity: cubit.show ? 1.0 : 0.0,
              duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500),
              child: FloatingActionButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  navigateTo(
                    context,
                    NewPostScreen(),
                  );
                },
                tooltip: 'Post',
                child: Icon(
                  IconBroken.Paper_Upload,
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
                elevation: 2.0,
              ),
            ),
          );
        } else {
          return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
        }
      },
    );
  }
}
```

now the app works fine after I restart the app and didn't gives me the error, but I I tried to login in first time it shows the `CircularProgressIndicator()` to infinite till I restart the app and login again..

here's all my `AppStates`:

```
abstract class AppStates {}

class AppInitialState extends AppStates {}

class AppGetUserLoadingState extends AppStates {}

class AppGetUserSuccessState extends AppStates {}

class AppGetUserErrorState extends AppStates {
  final String error;

  AppGetUserErrorState(this.error);
}

class AppChangeBottomNavBarState extends AppStates {}

class AppChangeBottomSheetState extends AppStates {}

class AppChangeModeState extends AppStates {}

class AppHandleReverseHideBottomWidgetState extends AppStates {}

class AppHandleForwardHideBottomWidgetState extends AppStates {}

class AppHideBottomWidgetState extends AppStates {}

class AppShowBottomWidgetState extends AppStates {}

class AppNewPostState extends AppStates {}
```

This is the below `LoginScreen`:

```
import 'package:conditional_builder/conditional_builder.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';
import 'package:mysocially/layout/social_layout.dart';
import 'package:mysocially/modules/register/register_screen.dart';
import 'package:mysocially/network/local/cache_helper.dart';
import 'package:mysocially/shared/components/components.dart';


import 'cubit/cubit.dart';
import 'cubit/states.dart';

class LoginScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  var formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  var emailController = TextEditingController();
  var passwordController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocProvider(
      create: (BuildContext context) => AppLoginCubit(),
      child: BlocConsumer<AppLoginCubit, AppLoginStates>(
        listener: (context, state) {
          if (state is AppLoginErrorState) {
            showToast(
              text: state.error,
              state: ToastStates.ERROR,
            );
          }
          if(state is AppLoginSuccessState) {
            CacheHelper.saveData(
              key: 'uId',
              value: state.uId,
            ).then((value)
            {
              navigateAndFinish(
                context,
                SocialLayout(),
              );
            });
          }
        },
        builder: (context, state) {
          return Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(),
            body: Center(
              child: SingleChildScrollView(
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                  child: Form(
                    key: formKey,
                    child: Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: [
                        Text(
                          'LOGIN',
                          style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4.copyWith(
                                color: Colors.black,
                              ),
                        ),
                        Text(
                          'Login now to to contact with friends',
                          style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyText1.copyWith(
                                color: Colors.grey,
                              ),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 30.0,
                        ),
                        defaultFormField(
                          controller: emailController,
                          type: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                          validate: (String value) {
                            if (value.isEmpty) {
                              return 'please enter your email address';
                            }
                          },
                          label: 'Email Address',
                          prefix: Icons.email_outlined,
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 15.0,
                        ),
                        defaultFormField(
                          controller: passwordController,
                          type: TextInputType.visiblePassword,
                          suffix: AppLoginCubit.get(context).suffix,
                          onSubmit: (value) {
                            if (formKey.currentState.validate()) {
                              AppLoginCubit.get(context).userLogin(
                                email: emailController.text,
                                password: passwordController.text,
                              );
                            }
                          },
                          isPassword: AppLoginCubit.get(context).isPassword,
                          suffixPressed: () {
                            AppLoginCubit.get(context)
                                .changePasswordVisibility();
                          },
                          validate: (String value) {
                            if (value.isEmpty) {
                              return 'password is too short';
                            }
                          },
                          label: 'Password',
                          prefix: Icons.lock_outline,
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 30.0,
                        ),
                        ConditionalBuilder(
                          condition: state is! AppLoginLoadingState,
                          builder: (context) => defaultButton(
                            function: () {
                              if (formKey.currentState.validate()) {
                                AppLoginCubit.get(context).userLogin(
                                  email: emailController.text,
                                  password: passwordController.text,
                                );
                              }
                            },
                            text: 'login',
                            isUpperCase: true,
                          ),
                          fallback: (context) =>
                              Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 15.0,
                        ),
                        Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                          children: [
                            Text(
                              'Don\'t have an account?',
                            ),
                            defaultTextButton(
                              function: () {
                                navigateTo(
                                  context,
                                  AppRegisterScreen(),
                                );
                              },
                              text: 'register',
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: `image: NetworkImage( '${userModel.cover}',),`  . I thought your error because that code.
 Is the `userModel.cover` has null possibility?

Comment: @GilangPratama thanks for your support, nope it's not the problem, I facing the same error :(

Comment: Have you tried making use of the state argument of the builder function of the BlocConsumer. For example, using if statements in the builder function where you check the value of the state argument.

Comment: @edgeboy7 could you explain to more, I didn't tries this really :)

Comment: Something like this: 
`builder: (context, state) {
 if(state is InitialState){}
 if(state is LoadingState){}
 if(state is LoadedState){}
}
`
Basically, using the state to determine what the builder function returns and what is shown on screen

Comment: @edgeboy7 yes I think I have tried it before but didn't work, you mean that to try it in the main right? because this error is in all over the app while getting any data from `FireStore`

Comment: @edgeboy7 could you check the updated code, I think I am near for the solution

Comment: If the screen is stuck on the CircularProgressIndicator, then your state probably is not updating or changing in your Cubit/Bloc

Answer (score 2):

I think your main confusion stems from the fact that you use (at least in name) a `Cubit`. A `Cubit` is a highly simplified type of `Bloc` to be used with single values. For example a Color or a number or a enum value.

You don't have that. You have lists of complex data. You should use a full blown `Bloc`. There are really good tutorials on the [flutter_bloc page](https://bloclibrary.dev/#/gettingstarted). Please don't stop at the simple tutorials, read one for complex data, because that is what you have.

The main difference is that you no longer directly access the `Bloc` for data, all data is communicated through the states. So for example your `Bloc` has no property `User`, only your `UserSuccessfullyLoaded` state has that property. This way, your compiler will guide you, when this data is available and when it is not.